# Get array of a specific field from a JSON Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

So I got a JSON array like this one:

```
"robots": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "foo",
        "last_connection": "2017-03-18 14:25:36"
    },{
        "id": 3,
        "name": "bar",
        "last_connection": "2017-03-19 17:28:39"
    },{
        "id": 8,
        "name": "foobar",
        "last_connection": "2017-04-18 11:22:33"
    }
]
```

Is there is simple way to get an array of ids from all my robots without doing a for loop over my array?

```
ids = [1, 3, 8]
```

Comment: `Array.map()` will do the job, just try

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, using the `Array.map` method.

```
const ids = robots.map(robot => robot.id);
```

`ids` will now be `[1, 3, 8]`.

Comment: Please do not answer this basic questions. There is a very high chance they have been answered before. Search such links and share their url and mark them as duplicate

Comment: What's wrong with answering a basic question if it's literally a one-liner?

Comment: Whats wrong is you are duplicating content. Old posts have different methods to achieve output, have discussions in comment and more importantly explanations which your answer is missing.